# Progress bar while fetching data from server

Tags: objective-c, ios

How can I show a progress bar in iOS app while my data is being downloaded synchronously from the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. When you fetch data synchronously, the fetching happens in the main thread and it blocks it while fetching and the UI uses the main thread to update itself, so until the fetching is complete you can't update anything on the UI. You should fetch asynchronously (in another thread) and update the UI (which runs on the main thread) on some checkpoints.

Comment: Oh i see, thanks for the valuable answer i was very much in need of this..
can u help me further?
give me more details on asynchronous fetching of data.
thnks in advance

Comment: You may need to read some articles on multithreading before you correctly implement async data fetching according to your needs. The general idea is to create a thread and execute the fetching there with some callbacks, but this is connected with knowledge at least about the terms `NSThread`, `NSOperation`, `NSOperationQueue`, `GCD` and the framework you are using to fetch the data..

Comment: Start with [Threading Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html)